# Unable to create Admin module in Codeigniter with HMVC extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, admin, codeigniter-hmvc

I am using HMVC extension [wiredesignz](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/f77a3fc9a6fdbfa47d70c921dac31d6d29a664e6?at=codeigniter-3.x) with codeigniter and I am unable to create Admin module. I am getting the following error

**The requested URL /hmvc/admin was not found on this server.**

however, if I rename admin directory to foo, bar or anything else it's working fine.The problem occurs only with admin directory. This is very awkward behavior. please help..

Comment: Well you'll have to shed some more light on this... ie some code and your folder structure. I'm using HMVC with an Admin Module which works fine. So you've got something funky going on. To state that changing the folder name makes it work, is rather odd!

Comment: Without knowing what you have done, I'd suggest that you walk through the instructions again on Wiredesignz Bit bucket page. It's easy to miss a step.